# How to call url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, url, frontend

I´m creating frontend for app and i need to call api function. I've got a url from api, which gives me json data like this:

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "First Like", "description": "Like at least 1", "image": "images/badges/FIRST_LIKE" }
```

I need to call some of those items in my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            //url to call http://eclipsewildflyserver-gobanit.com/rest/something/id=1 
        function getList(){

           var name = url.getItem("description");

       document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name.toString();

            }
```

I know im doing this completely wrong, and its my first atempt to do something like this, so I would really apreciate the help. Where should and how should I add url to code so i can pick a items i need? Thanks

EDIT: So i tried to replace with the ideas you gave me, and its still not working. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
    <script type = "texxt/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


<head>
 $.getJSON('http://eclipsewildflyserver-gobanit.rhcloud.com/AssignToolWebApp/rest/id=1', function (data) {
                var name = data;
                document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name.toString();

            });

</script>
</head>
<body onload=getList()>
<div id="TopHeader">
    <div id="header" class="container">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <h1 id="name"></h1>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</body></html>
```

Just trying to write a JSON string to page. Not working. I guess I´m doing something wrong.

Comment: You're going to have to use an ajax call, maybe consider using jQuery to make this easier on yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have a url to call `http://eclipsewildflyserver-gobanit.com/rest/something/id=1` 
and that is **.json** file . Therefore try this. 
You can use jQuery .getJSON() function:

```
$.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%27WRC%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback', function(data) {
    //data is the JSON string
});
```

Just replace this url with your relevant url.

Comment: should i put this in the function getList() or outside?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the json handling examples for the jquery library [here on their docs page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). There are some simple examples of using the getJson ajax method [here as well.](http://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/)

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript, you should use the XMLHttpRequest object. It's explained here [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

You can also do it easily with jQuery this way:

```
$.get(yourURL, function(your_response){/*Do whathever you want with your_response*/})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with you current code. First, your have the head tag in your script tag. Second, you tell the browser to run the "getList()" function when the body loads, but they "getList()" function is not defined. I assume you mean this to be the your API call.

I am not sure what you plan to do with the data. I am sure you do not mean to convert a JSON to a string and then set the content of that entire JSON to an h1 element. You probably need to parse your desired content from the JSON that is returned from the $.getJSON call to your API. You can sort that out later.

Modify your code as follows to successfully call your API and load the resulting JSON into the h1 tag:

```
<head>
<script type = "texxt/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 window.onload = $.getJSON('http://eclipsewildflyserver-gobanit.rhcloud.com/AssignToolWebApp/rest/id=1', function (data) {
                document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data.toString();
            });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="TopHeader">
    <div id="header" class="container">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <h1 id="name"></h1>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```